# ListboxItems containing image - memory issues

Tags: windows-phone-7, listboxitem

I have a design issue with my listbox on my view.
Currently it has following DataTemplate as ItemTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MovieItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" BorderThickness="5" Margin="3" Height="215" Width="140">
            <Image x:Name="MovieCover"                                                                                
                    toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                    Margin="0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="140"
                    Height="210">
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Cover}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
                </Image.Source>
                <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <gsextra:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MainViewModel.MovieItemSelectedCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                                                PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding MovieID}"
                                                ></gsextra:EventToCommand>
                    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Image>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

So as you can see, I have an image inside it that will download his content from the internet through an URI. Thanks to the new mango option BackgroundCreation ( cfr. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/13/off-thread-decoding-of-images-on-mango-how-it-impacts-you-application.aspx ) it load in background.

But I have a very large collection and even though I do 'paged' binding of the Listbox Source, I notice my memory keeps on going up, until it has consumed everything and the app crashes.

Then, I noticed this http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2011/01/17/images-and-memory-leaks-in-windows-phone-7/ so it would seem I need to cleanup the image itself, because of the image caching feature in wp7.

When I do this, everything works great in reference to memory, BUT now each time the user 'pages' through the listbox the images need to be redownloaded, resulting in an app that is almost not usable... because the user keeps on waiting for those images.

Any tips/tricks on how to go about this?

I also tried the [DefferedLoadListBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/08/never-do-today-what-you-can-put-off-till-tomorrow-deferredloadlistbox-and-stackpanel-help-windows-phone-7-lists-scroll-smoothly-and-consistently.aspx)

Comment: Have you considered doing the image downloading in code-behind? You could store images in isolated storage?

Comment: Hey Tom, would that help in this scenario? WP7 does this automatically with it's cache. The problem seems to be the cleanup, because loading new images (from storage or uri) makes the memory go up. It's the getting it down part I need ;)